# Tidy or TinyMce stripping essential html attributes in umbraco 4.7.2

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, bootstrapping, tidy

I've followed all guidelines related to this issue, including disabling tidy in umbracoSettings.config file:

```
<TidyEditorContent>False</TidyEditorContent>
```

and explicitly setting valid elements and attributes in the tinyMceConfig.config file. Also, I touch the web.config in order for changes to take effect, but none this leaves my markup intact.

For example, I need to use the holder.js library declaring an img element like so:

```
<img data-src="holder.js/140x140" />
```

When I click Update (*client-side action*) the data-src attribute is retained (although I haven't included it in the valid_elements list). When I save the page (*server-side action*) the resulting markup looks like this:

```
<img src="/" />
```

This leads me to suspect that it is Tidy doing the cleanup. However disabling it has no effect. Is there any way I can work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Locate the tinyMceConfig.config file.  Change the Valid Elements tag to allow for any markup:

```
<validElements><![CDATA[*[*]]]></validElements>
```

Comment: Or, to accommodate your specific example, locate img[ inside <validElements /> and add data-src to valid attributes (like so img[data-src|id|...] ).

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned, I've already tried both explicitly and with wildcards. The problem seems specific to the img tag where it strips any custom attribute (e.g. lala="123"), even though it is explicitly set in validElements.